# How to know the if ContactKey entered in a Journey Builder Path - Task Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a Journey Builder where every path create a Task in Salesforce, one of this path needs to create a Task in Salesforce when the email is null (decision split) and no action more. After this JB running, we noticed that the Tasks are not creating and now we want to know which contactkey went through that path.

The Journey History can not help because are thousand and thousand tasks. The Data View i think could help, but how theres no email to send i think i missed this;

Is there a workaround for this without entered in Salesforce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from using the filters in the Journey History, there isn't much you can do about it.
Also, it is not possible to export the contact data from Journey Builder.

Considering your scenario, the best way would be to query using workbench.

Going forward, you can do something like this -

1. Create a field in the DE, say for example 'flag'.
2. Go to your Journey, drag the 'Update contact' activity onto the canvas and place it next to the task creation.
3. Use the 'update contact' activity to select the DE and then set the 'flag' field to a value 'true'.

After the journey runs, you can export the records from the DE and verify. If the flag value is true, then a task has been created for that contact. Else, it is not.